# What exactly is Hawtio?

Tags: spring, apache-camel, spring-camel, hawtio

I don't understand what exactly Hawtio does.

If you could give an introduction to Hawtio:

- What exactly is it?
- What added value does it gives me as a Camel\ Spring developer?
  Please explain what Hawtio is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hawtio a monitoring  web console for java application. its  popular usage is with apache camel . It visualizes the data it receives from jmx.  Jolokia takes over the process of getting the data from jmx and acts as a new bridge. With Hawtio you can do the following items and much more.

- How many times has the route worked (live reload)?
- Show Jvm parameters
- Heap objects and count
- How many errors were received?
- How many transactions were successful?
- Eip of java code
- Changing log level
- Changing camel component attribütes
- etc